# Onclick image the gallery opens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a mobile application, I am trying to make an image as a button: I have an image and I want to click on it, then when I click the mobile gallery opens so that I can upload a photo.

Any help please?

Comment: Can you show, what have you tried so far?

Comment: <div id = "profilepic">
<button>
<img src="Images/profilepic.png" width="170" height="170"/>
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
</button>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you want to open file-uploader on image button click! Right?
If so, you can use pure javascript / jQuery as following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="profilepic">
    <input id="fileSelector" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
    <button id="clickButton" onClick="openFileUpload();"><img src="Images/profilepic.png" width="170" height="170"/></button>
</div>
```

For jQuery append this to head of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Wrap following code in head too.

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickButton').on('click', function(){
        $('#fileSelector').click();
    });
});
```

OR **Javascript:**

```
function openFileUpload(){
    document.getElementById('fileSelector').click();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mas5qr1o/1/

See demo here:
[jQuery DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5vjbjtjg/)
[Javascript DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mas5qr1o/1/)

Comment: where do i write the jquery code please?

Comment: You need to wrap above code in $(document).ready(function(){ Above code goes here }); in script tag.

Comment: Also, you need to download jQuery library or link its CDN in head of document.

Comment: yes thats what i did but still not working :/

Comment: Ok, are you linking your jQuery library from correct path?

Comment: i am doing the following:

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#clickButton').on('click', function(){
$('#fileSelector').click();});
 </script>

Comment: Okay, if you are having issue with jQuery, you can try simple javascript to do so. See my updates.

Comment: yes it work :) know how can i remove the choose file button please?

Comment: Add this class to your CSS section: #fileSelector::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `jquery`

```
$('#clickButton').on('click', function(){
    $('#fileSelector').trigger('click');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/5vjbjtjg/2/)

Comment: I am writing the script code in the html but still not working for me :/

Comment: did you call the jquery library in your code.?

Comment: yes:<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $('#clickButton').on('click', function(){
  $('#fileSelector').trigger('click');
  });
 </script>

Comment: is your file is placed in the correct directory.